# Does rails 4 asset_path helper uses asset.prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I configured my rails app to use a different asset prefix, by editing the file `conf/application.rb`.

`+config.assets.prefix = '/wrapper/thing'`

It works for asset pipeline but when I try to use it on my view.

`<%= asset_path('milk.png') %>`

It still outputs `"/assets/milk.png"` instead of `"/wrapper/thing/milk.png"`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should double-check your file names as there was a report of a similar bug which turned out to be a typo.

Basically what happens in Rails 4 is that the prefix is omitted if the asset doesn't exist.

You can test the behavior in the Rails Console as they demonstrate on the thread:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15873

```
$ rails new path-test
$ touch app/assets/images/hello.png
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
>> Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
=> "/assets"
>> ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path "hello.png"
=> "/assets/hello.png"
>> ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path "foo.png"
=> "/foo.png"
```

FYI, you will likely get a quicker response to Rails questions over on Stackoverflow where there is much larger Rails community: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank @wayne-phipps this answers my question "Basically what happens in Rails 4 is that the prefix is omitted if the asset doesn't exist." Also I didn't notice I thought I was on stackoverflow ;/ sorry.